# Javascript Calculation issue when there is a Space during calculating input value

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

```js
function divideBy() {
  var w = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var y = w / x;
  y = y.toFixed(2);
  var z = y;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
  var a = document.getElementById("first1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("second1").value;
  var c = a / b;
  var d = c;
  d = d.toFixed(2);
  var e = d
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = e;
  document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('modal1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="normal">
    <div align="right">SGST @ 9% :</div>
  </td>
  <td nowrap class="normal">
    <div align="right">
      <div id="divCheckbox1" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" step=0.001 id="first" value=1 000>
        <input type="number" step=0.001 id="second" value=2 .0>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="modal1" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
      <span id="answer"></span>
      <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal">
      <div align="right">CGST @ 9% :</div>
    </td>
    <td nowrap class="normal">
      <div align="right">
        <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
          <input type="number" step=0.001 id="first1" value=1 000>
          <input type="number" step=0.001 id="second1" value=2 .0>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="modal" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
        <span id=answer1></span>
        <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
    </td>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please clarify exactly **what** your problem is? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? In order for us to help you better, please let us know more **about** your code. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: So the issue is with          <input type="number" step=0.001 id="first1" value=1 000>
the script isnt calculating 1 000 as 1000 , its considering the value as 1.

Comment: because `value=1 000` means attribute value=1 and some (ignored) attribute called `000` ... HTML is very forgiving with "garbage" attributes

Comment: Without knowing what your current problem is, I can already tell you that your `value=1 000` will *not* assign the value of "1000" to the input element. You should use `value="1 000"` instead. And even then the resultant string "1 000" can only be used in calculations once you removed the blank from it, like with `stringvar.replace(" ","") `.

Comment: Can you guys help me out and show me where im going wrong and where should i use stringvar.replace(" ","")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function removeSpace(text){
         return text.replace(/\s/g,'');
    }
    
        function divideBy() {
          var w = removeSpace(document.getElementById("first").value);
          var x = removeSpace(document.getElementById("second").value);
          var y = w / x;
          y = y.toFixed(2);
          var z = y;
          document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
          var a = removeSpace(document.getElementById("first1").value);
          var b = removeSpace(document.getElementById("second1").value);
          var c = a / b;
          var d = c;
          d = d.toFixed(2);
          var e = d
          document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = e;
          document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById('modal1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
```

```html
    
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="normal">
            <div align="right">SGST @ 9% :</div>
          </td>
          <td nowrap class="normal">
            <div align="right">
              <div id="divCheckbox1" >
                <input type="text" step=0.001 id="first"  value="1 000"/>
                <input type="text"  step=0.001 id="second" value="2 .0"/>
              </div>
              <button type="button" id="modal1" onclick="divideBy()">click here </button>
              <span id="answer"></span>
              <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
              </div>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="normal">
              <div align="right">CGST @ 9% :</div>
            </td>
            <td nowrap class="normal">
              <div align="right">
                <div id="divCheckbox">
                  <input type="text"  step=0.001 id="first1" value="5 000"/>
                  <input type="text"  step=0.001 id="second1" value="3 .0"/>
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="modal" onclick="divideBy()">Click here1</button>
                <span id=answer1></span>
                <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: I would need the code to work along with the white spaces. it should accept 1 000 as 1000

Comment: @RalphLobo I have Updated input from number to text. but for text-box control, you need to do numeric validation

Comment: @RalphLobo : I just answer updated. now you can try with above solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove white spaces from input before processing anything.

```js
   function divideBy() {
              var w = document.getElementById("first").value;
                var temp1='';
                for(var i=0; i < w.length; i++){ //Remove white spaces
                    if(w.charAt(i)!==' ')
                        temp1+=w.charAt(i);
                }
                
              var x = document.getElementById("second").value;
                var temp2='';
                for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){ //Remove white spaces
                    if(x.charAt(i)!==' ')
                        temp2+=x.charAt(i);
                }
              
                w=parseFloat(temp1); 
                x=parseFloat(temp2);
                
              var y = w / x;
              y = y.toFixed(2);
              var z = y;
              document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
              var a = document.getElementById("first1").value;
              var b = document.getElementById("second1").value;
              var c = a / b;
              var d = c;
              d = d.toFixed(2);
              var e = d
              document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = e;
              document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
              document.getElementById('modal1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
```

Comment: I would need the code to work along with the white spaces.

Comment: All suggested answers works with white spaces. If you need your compiler to accept blank spaces then its wrong requirement.  Instead you write a code which accept blank spaces- removes it - and then processes the input.

Comment: I tried the code. its still condering the input value of 1 000 as 1 but not 1000

Answer (score 0):

Since you said its number,its just taking the value before space.

Html:

```
<tr>
<td class="normal">
<div align="right">SGST @ 9% :</div>
</td>
<td nowrap class="normal">
<div align="right">
  <div id="divCheckbox1" style="display: none;">
    <input step=0.001 id="first" value="1 000">
    <input step=0.001 id="second" value="2 .0">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="modal1" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
  <span id="answer"></span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="normal">
  <div align="right">CGST @ 9% :</div>
</td>
<td nowrap class="normal">
  <div align="right">
    <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
      <input step=0.001 id="first1" value="1 000">
      <input step=0.001 id="second1" value="2 .0">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="modal" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
    <span id=answer1></span>
    <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
function divideBy() {
var w = document.getElementById("first").value ;
var x = document.getElementById("second").value;
var y = w.replace(" ","") / x.replace(" ","");
y = y.toFixed(2);
var z = y;
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
var a = document.getElementById("first1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("second1").value;
var c = a.replace(" ","") / b.replace(" ","");
var d = c;
d = d.toFixed(2);
var e = d
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = e;
document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('modal1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out in comments value = 1 000 wont work, because me and you can see 1 000 as 1000 but the computer cannot. It assumes it as value = 1 (000 is ignored). So you can write it as value = 1000 ans also in the next line value = 2.0. Do not give spaces in between digits (because the language doesn't allows that.

Also you are not closing both divs in each tr.

So, to make the code work, all you need to do is change the value = 1 000 to value = 1000 and value = 2 .0 to value = 2.0, and check all the elements are properly placed according to HTML syntax.

This snippet works according to your javascript code.

```js
function divideBy() {
  var w = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var y = w / x;
  y = y.toFixed(2);
  var z = y;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = z;
  var a = document.getElementById("first1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("second1").value;
  var c = a / b;
  var d = c;
  d = d.toFixed(2);
  var e = d
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = e;
  document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('modal1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="normal">
    <div align="right">SGST @ 9% :</div>
  </td>
  <td nowrap class="normal">
    <div align="right">
      <div id="divCheckbox1" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" step=0.001 id="first" value=1 000>
        <input type="number" step=0.001 id="second" value=2 .0>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="modal1" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
      <span id="answer"></span>
      <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
      </div>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal">
      <div align="right">CGST @ 9% :</div>
    </td>
    <td nowrap class="normal">
      <div align="right">
        <div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
          <input type="number" step=0.001 id="first1" value=1000>
          <input type="number" step=0.001 id="second1" value=2.0>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="modal" onclick="divideBy()"></button>
        <span id=answer1></span>
        <span style="display:inline-block; width: 5;"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: i agree, but is there a way i can make the computer accept 1 000 as 1000